# How Google decides the image results for the Image tab?

Tags: google, google-search, googlebot, google-image-search, image-search

Whenever I search on Google, Google shows the results cards in All tab at SERP and Images at Images tab. So how Google decides which image will be placed at first position or at first row according to my query?

**Note:** My query is not about image specific results. Query is about the definition result or can be sorted out from the using of snippet card. Using the image tab is just for better understanding in frequent way.